# How to read the arguments of user input in python?

Tags: python, arguments, user-input

I'm trying to get the arguments of user input in python. I want to prompt the user to type something, and then store the words that they type in variables. I've tried doing 'sys.argv[1]' and 'cmd.argv[1]', but I just keep getting errors.

```
import sys
import os

print("Usage: .run <host> <time>")

cmd = input("test@0.0.0.0:~# ")

host = cmd.argv[2]
time = cmd.argv[3]

print("HOST: " + host)
print("TIME: " + time)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to make your program's prompt look like a shell prompt? That's a little misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of python's `input` (in 3.x.x) is a string. You'd use `sys.argv` if you were calling your code with the terminal, like

`$ python mycode.py argument1 argument2`

but as it stands, a string doesn't have `.argv` functionality.

The python [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function might be helpful. If you need more complicated parsing, eg to enable `'argument 1' argument\ 2` being parsed into `['argument 1', 'argument 2']`, you might find [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) a useful library (included with python)